# c - fopen returns NULL even when the file is there

Tags: c, linux, unix, fopen

I am trying to fopen() on a complete UNIX path, i.e.,

```
fopen("/dir1/file1.raw", "rb");
```

The file is there and is rw-. However, fopen returns NULL. errno says no such file or directory. Any ideas?

Comment: What says `errno`? There are many reasons why `fopen` returns `NULL`...

Comment: errno says no file or directory. Just updated the question.

Comment: You have a directory named "dir1" directly off your root? Do you have permission to open it?

Comment: This could have many issues: Is the file _really_ there, is it _really_ readable by the same user which is running this program, is the filename _really_ file1.raw (and does not contain some crazy Unicode things in it)...

Comment: @Bob: I am root user.

Comment: What permissions do you have on the directory containing the file?  What does `file /complete/path/to/file1.raw` say?

Comment: @akluth: how can I know about that?

Comment: @Iceman what I mean is, is /dir1 a valid path or is dir1 actually under another directory?

Comment: @Bob: yes /dir1 is valid. It's from root.

Comment: @Iceman have you tried other Unix programs such as "cat" or "ls" ? Give them the same path from the same place you are running your program and see if they open it.

Comment: @Iceman what is the errno value? Is it a 2 or a 3 ?

Comment: @Iceman, like the username, can you give the output of `ls -la`?

Comment: @Bob: errno is 2. I have tried ls -l to check permissions and it works.

Comment: are you doing any `chroot` in your code ?

Comment: @Iceman yes, but can "cat" open it? Try running cat from the same spot as your program with the same path/filename. Also, cd to your path and try cat in the directory with the file. It's a sanity-check.

Comment: I guess your program does `chroot()` or `setuid()`. Just before the `fopen()` can you add a call to `system("ls -l /dir1/file1.raw")` and report the result?

Comment: Check the output of `ls -ld / /dir1 /dir1/file1.raw` - adjust as necessary to inspect every directory between `/` and your file if you've actually obfuscated the path for the sake of your question. In order to open a file for reading, your process *must* have read and execute permissions on every directory leading to the file (slightly over-stated - read permissions on directories not strictly necessary, but it's unusual to see directories without it), and read permissions on the file itself

Comment: @jxh: ls: No such file or directory (/dir1/file1.raw)

Comment: @Iceman: This is evidence your program is executing under a changed environment from your shell. Probably due to a `chroot()` call.

Comment: looks you are in `chroot` environment.. in `c` code, check the inode number of `/` (root) directory using `stat` call.. man page => http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat..

Comment: If you are root, is the directory NFS-mounted?  If so, you get the privileges of user 'nobody', and you can't read the file unless the general public can.

Comment: Thanks jxh, VoidPointer, Jonathen. I'm investigating this further, will keep you updated.

Comment: Use `strace` on your program executable to find out what actual system calls it is doing.

Comment: Are there any `/../` sequences in the file's path?

Comment: What's the output of `md5sum /dir1/file1.raw`? (The specific value isn't important; what's relevant is whether you get an error message.)