# error while opening file through a c++ program via bash script

Tags: c++, bash

I have a c++ program which read and writes to a file. When i invoke it from bash shell such as `./modifyFile /path/to/file.abc.12.def`, it works. But, if i do the same from a bash script such as show below:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ./modifyFile /path/to/file.abc.12.def
```

the c++ program is unable to open file. I print the filename, that is passed to the program and output is correct.

Infact, if i copy the filename which is printed by the c++ program and manually execute it on bash script such as `./modifyFile /path/to/file.abc.12.def`, it works. So there are no user permissions issue either.

The c++ code, where file is not found is shown below

```
    fstream aFile(filename.c_str(), fstream::ate | fstream::in | fstream::out);
    if(!aFile)
    {
            cerr << "Unable to open file!" << endl; // this prints from bash script
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

Comment: Is the path given actually absolute? If not, is the file accessible from the current directory?

Comment: OK - what kind of error does the file open function return? Could you perhaps provide some code?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to open file"? What error code or exception are you getting when you try to open the file?

Comment: Works fine for me - only other thing I can think of is that bash is doing something with the file name. Are there any "unusual" characters in the path (i.e. dollar signs, backslashes, other punctuation)?

Comment: @Jimm check this question. It doesn't have any answer. but get all the information related to question and provide us. This would reduce turn-around time.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347745/c-fopen-returns-null-even-when-the-file-is-there#comment25171388_17347745

Comment: Have you printed out the file name that the C++ code is failing to open?  Maybe it isn't the name you think it is...

Comment: Try putting quotes './modifyFile' '/path/to/file.abc.12.def' . The bash might be messing with some characters.

Comment: Does your bash script contain some unprintable characters at the end of the line, perhaps?

Comment: @ams it could contain CR-LF as line ending. The error is that his program doesn't output neither the filename in quotes nor the error string.

Comment: One thing you could try is running both with "strace -f -e trace=open -s 1024" in front of them and see if the open() calls' arguments look the same.  They'll generally show up near the end of the run.